# gcc compile error for gnu readline() to read from stdin

Tags: gcc, compiler-errors, stdout, stdin, readline

HI, guys,

I write a small program, named "ioprogram.c", with gnu readline library, refering various documentation on the Internet. however, gcc reports the following errors. what is my problem?

```
#include <readline/readline.h>
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    char* c = readline("");
    int len = strlen(c);
    for(int i=0; i<len; i++)
    {    
        printf("%c", *(c+i));  
        fflush(stdout);        
    }
    free(c);
}
```

gcc errors:

```
In file included from /usr/include/readline/readline.h:37,
                 from ioprogram.c:1:
/usr/include/readline/rltypedefs.h:65: error: expected ‘)’ before ‘*’ token
In file included from ioprogram.c:1:
/usr/include/readline/readline.h:416: error: expected ‘)’ before ‘*’ token
/usr/include/readline/readline.h:532: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘*’ token
/usr/include/readline/readline.h:533: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘*’ token
/usr/include/readline/readline.h:555: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘*’ token
/usr/include/readline/readline.h:823: error: expected specifier-qualifier-list before ‘FILE’
ioprogram.c: In function ‘main’:
ioprogram.c:7: error: ‘for’ loop initial declaration used outside C99 mode
```

Thanks in advance for any comments.

Comment: The code builds for me, and I see no syntax errors in your code, but the error you're getting suggests there is one. Please provide the version of gcc you used, and how you're trying to compile the code. Remember that you need to link against the readline library("-lreadline").

Comment: Thank you gamen. The gcc version is gcc (GCC) 4.1.2 20080704 (Red Hat 4.1.2-48). And I use "gcc ioprogram.c -o ioprogram" to compile.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try compiling with
`gcc ioprogram.c -o ioprogram -lreadline -lncurses`